# Showing a post depending on the Custom Field value

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coach_location', true) == "Austria"): ?>
```

...this works, but manually checking each country and repeating the post content code is getting arduous, is it possible to do the country check automatically show the post content?

So instead of checking each country like so:

```
if austria: echo title & the_content
if australia: echo title & the_content
if south_africa: echo title & the_content
... all 196 countries of the world
```

is it possible to automate this so I echo the title and content just once?

Comment: Have you tried loop by countries then query posts? or you're looking for a wat to group posts by meta value?

Comment: Exactly, group posts by meta value. List all coaches of Australia together, and so on..

Comment: Please check the updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to group posts by meta value, try the following code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array ( 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
        'meta_key' => 'coach_location',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ) 
);
```

Please refer to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Let's say you'd like to print the Coach Location for each group, the sample code should be:

```
$last_location = '';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $location = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'coach_location', true );
    if ( $last_location != $location ){
        echo $location;
        $last_location = $location;
    }
    // echo the reset content
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Yes, but this is still manual, I have to check each country. Austria, Australia, USA, etc..

Comment: Could you be more specific on what is the scenario?

Comment: Sure, edited the description

Comment: You won't believe, I did EXACTLY that and came here to post and found your answer :) Just one more thing please, how do I print the meta value of the "coach_location" once for each group to separate them.

Comment: Hey there, I've updated my answer to respond to your comment.